# Kafka producer creates topic but is not able to send messages

Tags: scala, cloudera-cdh, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I'm new to Scala and Kafka and I've run into some trouble.

I'm trying to connect a scala kafka producer to a kafka server that is installed on a cloudera express server.
I have done this already once in VMs with [these instructions](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#quickstart_startserver/) and didn't have any problems.

When I run the producer the desired topic is created but none of the messages is sent, or so I think.

Here follows some of the code:

*Kafka producer*

```
import java.util.Properties
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.{KafkaProducer, ProducerRecord}

class KafkaProducerManager {

    val props = new Properties()
    props.put("bootstrap.servers", KafkaServer.KAFKA_ADDRESS)
    props.put("acks", "all")
    props.put("retries", "2")
    props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000")
    props.put("linger.ms", "1")
    props.put("block.on.buffer.full", "true")
    props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
    props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
    props.put("auto.create.topics.enable", "true")

    val producer = new KafkaProducer[String, String](props)

   def startCounter() {
       println("Start Producer Counter")
       for (i <- 1 to 100) {
           producer.send(new ProducerRecord("test-counter", i.toString, "Package " + i))
           println("Producer - Send: " + i)
       }

       println("Closing producer")
       producer.close()
   }
}
```

When I execute the run method, I see "Producer - Send: #" as output of this and I get no errors.
So I assume that this piece of code has sent the messages to Kafka.

I started the following on the kafka server before I ran the producer:

```
 kafka-console-consumer --zookeeper zk:2181 --topic test-counter
```

But here I see nothing happens.

When I check for the topic, that the producer is supposed to create, is in the list.

```
kafka-topics -zookeeper zk:2181 --list
```

I also have a similar problem with the consumer:

```
import java.util.{Arrays, Properties}
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer

class KafkaConsumerManager {

    val props = new Properties()
    props.put("bootstrap.servers", KafkaServer.KAFKA_ADDRESS)
    props.put("group.id", "testGroup")
    props.put("enable.auto.commit", "true")
    props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000")
    props.put("linger.ms", "1")
    props.put("session.timeout.ms", "3000")
    props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
    props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
    props.put("zookeeper.connect", KafkaServer.ZOOKEEPER_ADDRESS)

    val consumer = new KafkaConsumer[String, String](props)

    def start() {
        println("Start Consumer")
        consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("test-counter"))

        while (true) {
            val records = consumer.poll(100)
            val iterator = records.iterator()

            while (iterator.hasNext) {
                val record = iterator.next()
                printf("Consumer: offset = %d, key = %s, value = %s \n", record.offset(), record.key(), record.value())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I create messages on the server via kafka-console-producer I see them appear in the kafka-console-consumer on the server, but not in the consumer I wrote.

```
kafka-console-producer --broker-list ks:9092 --topic test-counter
```

The KafkaServer.ZOOKEEPER_ADDRESS is the same as the argument zk:2181 with kafka-console-consumer and the KafkaServer.KAFKA_ADDRESS is the same as the argument ks:9092 with the kafka-console-producer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the code and found that:

- one should specify **key** and **value** **deserializers** in consumer
  properties:

  ```
   props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
   props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
  ```
- there is a problem with `session.timeout.ms` property. From [here](https://kafka.apache.org/090/configuration.html):

  > heartbeat.interval.ms - ... The value **must be set lower** than **session.timeout.ms** ... **default: 3000**

  It means that you should either increase your `session.timeout.ms`
  value or simply **remove** the line because default value for the
  property is `30000` which is greater than default
  `heartbeat.interval.ms`.

After performing the corrections the code works.

Comment: I will try this immediatly

Comment: With this changes the problem still exists.
But now I'm able to see it's cause by

`java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: no further information.`

For some reason both, producer and consumer are not able to connect to ks:9092.

Comment: I have tried this code with another kafka server and there it works fine. It seems to be some issue with our kafkaserver on cloudera and the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

if you are running in windows machine? and following quickstart guide, I had the same issue producer/consumer not giving any error but running either, you need to set kafka_home in your envrionment variabel KAFKA_HOME=C:\kafka_2.13-2.6.0
and then for zooker/server/topic/consumer/producer everything run under your kafka/windows
example: for consumer
%KAFKA_HOME%/bin/windows/kafka-console-consumer.bat --topic quickstart-events --from-beginning --bootstrap-server localhost:9092

Comment: While there is useful information here, it is hard to read in it's current formatting.